# Try to install a package without any other action

Tags: apt, 18.04, 20.04, package-management, dependencies

I know it is not a preferred action, but for a distupgrade from bionic to focal (and later to jammy) I have to install a package from focal to bionic first. This is because I have an additional source (packages.matrix.org). To do a do-release-upgrade I must upgrade to the latest Matrix, with needs packages from focal.

When I try to install the required deb file from the command line (downloaded from packages.ubuntu.com), apt want to uninstall essential packages:

```
$ sudo apt --simulate --ignore-missing install ./libsystemd0_245.4-4ubuntu3.20_amd64.deb
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'libsystemd0' instead of './libsystemd0_245.4-4ubuntu3.20_amd64.deb'
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  dbus-user-session docker-ce-rootless-extras friendly-recovery init libnss-systemd libpam-systemd plymouth plymouth-theme-ubuntu-text snapd systemd systemd-sysv ubuntu-standard
The following packages will be upgraded:
  libsystemd0
WARNING: The following essential packages will be removed.
This should NOT be done unless you know exactly what you are doing!
  init systemd-sysv (due to init)
1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 12 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
```

How can I solve this problem until the dist-upgrade is executed?

Comment: Advice: Uninstall all packages from non-Ubuntu sources, and disable those non-Ubuntu sources. Return your system to as close to stock condition as possible. Then do your release-upgrade (different from a `dist-upgrade`). Then reboot. Then begin re-enabling your non-Ubuntu sources and reinstalling the software. This site is knee-deep in the tears of folks who tried to take shortcuts (`dist-upgrade` instead of release-upgrade, leaving non-Ubuntu sources enabled) and learned, to their sorrow, that shortcuts ruined their system.

Comment: The reason for this server is to run the installed Matrix server. So, to uninstall that non-Ubuntu package would not lead to the desired goal.
Is it possible tu upgrade the Ubuntu without uninstalling Matrix?

Comment: Why are you specifying that particular version of libsystemd0? It will forever block a release-upgrade, as it is not the most updated version. This is starting to seem like a possible [XY Question](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem).

Comment: It is the minimum version of libsystemd0.


$ sudo apt install --only-upgrade matrix-synapse-py3

Reading package lists... Done

Building dependency tree

Reading state information... Done

Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.

The following packages have unmet dependencies:

 matrix-synapse-py3 : Depends: libsystemd0 (>= 245) but 237-3ubuntu10.57 is to be installed

Comment: You can reinstall Matrix post upgrade, so I see no problem in uninstalling it.

Comment: Instead of upgrading through two LTS releases, consider fresh installing 22.04 and then install matrix and other software.

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to solve this problem is to remove packages.matrix.org from your software sources in `/etc/apt/`, run `sudo apt update`, and uninstall the Matrix software so that you will be able to upgrade for Ubuntu 18.04 to Ubuntu 20.04 without removing essential packages which could damage your system. After the upgrade has been finished you can install the latest version of Matrix. Alternatively it might save time if you fresh installed Ubuntu 22.04 instead of upgrading to it in two stages and then reinstalled Matrix in Ubuntu 22.04.